# "Almost for nothing"?

Tags: word-order

My teacher said that there's no way to say "almost for nothing" (I wrote this in my essay), but I'm sure that I've heard this exact word order.

Which is correct: "Almost for nothing" or "for almost nothing"?

Comment: In *most* contexts, we put adjectival ***almost*** right next to the word it actually modifies (in your context, hat's the noun ***nothing*** - ***almost*** doesn't modify the preposition ***for***). But idiomatically, it's ***almost for free*** rather than ***for almost free***.

Comment: They mean different things: I bought it for a penny (for almost nothing), or I nearly got it free (almost for nothing).

Comment: Both are correct, contextwise: almost for nothing: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22almost%20for%20nothing%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1945,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en for almost nothing : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20almost%20nothing%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1987,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+for+nothing%2Cfor+almost+nothing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmost%20for%20nothing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20almost%20nothing%3B%2Cc0) "for almost nothing" is much more common, but they were similar 200 years ago.